# argument out of range exception was unhandled

Tags: winforms, vb.net, progress-bar

Sou iniciante no VB.NET e estou criando um jogo simples de simulação, tem a fome, sede etc, no progressbar fome o máximo que chega é 100.

Quando você come algo restaura 5, se eu estou com 98 e como dá erro.

Queria saber se tem algum código pra especificar que o maximo que pode chegar é 100 e não passar disso

Como por exemplo estar com 98 de fome e em vez de ir pra 103 ir pra 100, só restaurando 2.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar2.Value = Fome
```

---

```
Module Module1
Public Fome As Integer = 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `Math.Min`

> Queria saber se tem algum código pra especificar que o maximo que pode
>   chegar é 100 e não passar disso

A [função Min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h5sbzt2y(v=vs.110).aspx) da classe `Math` pode fazer esse controle de valor máximo.
Ela vai comparar os dois valores e retornar o menor deles. Se `Fome` passar de 100, vai retornar 100.

Exemplo:

```
ProgressBar2.Value = Math.Min(Fome, 100)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo.

Comment: @LukasOliver Se funcionou, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como certa. =)